# UpdateRequest via a Script in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to update a propertie in a nested object in Elasticsearch via Java. My mapping looks as follows:

```
"mappings": {
    "cv":{
        "properties":{
            "name":{"type":"string"},
            "skills": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "skillId": {"type": "string"},
                    "yearExperience": {"type": "integer"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is update the property 'skillId' within the nested object 'skills' with a UpdateRequest and the script feature. All the skills that match the entered id, should be replaced with the new id. The code i've come up with so far is:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("cv", "cv", "AVDdS7_u8voLjZ32rEnT")
            .addScriptParam("oldId", "AVDdSy4u8voLjZ32rEi4")
            .addScriptParam("newId", "AVDdSy4u8voLjZ32rEi0")
            .script("foreach(item : ctx._source.skills) {if(item['skillId'] == oldId) { item['skillId'] = newId })}");
client.update(updateRequest);
```

I've tried some parts of the scripts and some of the them worked. The part which didn't work for me is doing something with the nested object.

EDIT: Alright thanks to slawek I managed to get a working script:

```
String script = "def oldElement = ctx._source.skills.find {it.skillsId.equals(oldId) };"
+ "def newElement = oldElement; newElement.skillsId = newId;"
+ "ctx._source.skills -= oldElement;"
+ "ctx._source.skills += newElement;";
```

Comment: Here one of the script I use https://gist.github.com/zarucki/4fb3c342188f14a21c6c . It uses tags as nested objects with `tpi` as id and `tti` as string array. Maybe it will help you.